# Merging two (messy) datasets

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two datasets each containing the same columns. First column is name then some other characteristics follow.

Many of the data is missing, empty elements, but all of the names are there.

I want to merge the list, deleting duplicate information but conserving all the information there is

Example: 
First dataset

```
Name V1 V2
A    2   3
B        9
```

Second dataset

```
Name V1 V2
A        3
B    4   9
C    18
```

Here is how far I got before I got stuck:

```
S1=read.xlsx2("... /Exercise_Data_Week_2.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1") 
S2=read.xlsx2("... /w2/Exercise_Data_Week_2.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet2") 

alldata=rbind(S1,S2)  #18305 obs
MName <- unique(alldata["Name"]) #13738 obs
```

EDIT: Desired dataset after merging is (as Colonel guessed)

```
#   Name V1 V2
#1:    A  2  3
#2:    B  4  9
#3:    C 18 NA
```

EDIT2: Note that this is not the data I am working with, it's a MUCH simplified version. So I am looking for a way that is generalizable...

NB: This is an Excel exercise from the MOOC *EX101x Data Analysis: Take it to the MAX()*. I am investing my time doing it in R instead (at the beginning it is much harder but I believe in the long-run I will save time with R). The course is open and free so I guess I am allowed to post the data for the exercise: https://courses.edx.org/c4x/DelftX/EX101x/asset/Exercise_Data_Week_2.xlsx

Comment: So what is the desired output here? How exactly do you want to merge these sample datasets?

Comment: In words: I want to keep one instance of each name and fill in the other columns as well as possible.

Comment: does the below answers your question?

Comment: They do exactly what I was looking for.  I was hoping for something easier to understand, but I guess it I just have to study R harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in base R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name=c('A','B'), V1=c(2,NA), V2=c(3,9) );
df2 <- data.frame(Name=c('A','B','C'), V1=c(NA,4,18), V2=c(3,9,NA) );
aggregate(.~Name, rbind(df1,df2), function(v) na.omit(v)[1], na.action=NULL );
##   Name V1 V2
## 1    A  2  3
## 2    B  4  9
## 3    C 18 NA
```

This solution makes the assumption that if there are duplicate non-NA values between the two input data.frames, it is always acceptable to take the first of them.

Comment: Worked when I started by replacing empty values by NA, otherwise your code  would put 1 in their place. Now I just need to understand all the details of the aggregate functions so I can apply this to different settings. Cheers.